# Left, center, right three buttons in bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently attempting to center three buttons inside of a container. I have gotten very close, however I can not seem to keep all the buttons in one row. I have tried text-[left, right, center] as well as pull-[left,right].

I have included a skeleton shell to provide the base layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- meta -->

        <!-- refs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- scripts -->

        <title>The title</title>
    </head>
    <body>



<!-- MASTER CONTAINER -->
<div class="container-fluid page-container">

    <!-- divide main content into three sections left, middle, right -->
    <!-- top section container -->
    <div class="row top-container">
        <!-- top section -->
        <div class="col-sm-12">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- LEFT CONTAINER (vertical)       -->
        <!-- left side -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Save Trick</button>
        </div

        <!-- right side -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Gold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Black</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Blue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Green</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">White</button>
        </div>




        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <!-- MIDDLE CONTAINER (horizontal)  -->
            <div class="middle-container">
                <div class="middle-top">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Approach</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Street/Half Pipe</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Coach Assisted</button>
                </div>

                <div class="middle-video">
    4
                </div>

                <div class="middle-textinput">
    5
                </div>

                <div class="middle-bottom">
    6
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- RIGHT CONTAINER (vertical)     -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Gold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Black</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Blue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Green</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">White</button>
        </div

        <!-- right side -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Gold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Black</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Blue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Green</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">White</button>
        </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Style.css (to display box model)

```
* {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try giving the center button `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simplest solution

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- meta -->

        <!-- refs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- scripts -->

        <title>The title</title>
    </head>
    <body>



<!-- MASTER CONTAINER -->
<div class="container-fluid page-container">

    <!-- divide main content into three sections left, middle, right -->
    <!-- top section container -->
    <div class="row top-container">
        <!-- top section -->
        <div class="col-sm-12">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- LEFT CONTAINER (vertical)       -->
        <!-- left side -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Save Trick</button>
        </div

        <!-- right side -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Gold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Black</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Blue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Green</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">White</button>
        </div>




        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <!-- MIDDLE CONTAINER (horizontal)  -->
            <div class="middle-container">
                <div class="middle-top"><center>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Approach</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Street/Half Pipe</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Coach Assisted</button></center>
                </div>

                <div class="middle-video">
    4
                </div>

                <div class="middle-textinput">
    5
                </div>

                <div class="middle-bottom">
    6
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- RIGHT CONTAINER (vertical)     -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Gold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Black</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Blue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Green</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">White</button>
        </div

        <!-- right side -->
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Gold</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Black</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Blue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">Green</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button">White</button>
        </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While the <center> tags did not work initially, I was able to incorporate pull-[left, right] onto the two outside buttons and get this working properly.